# XSLT match multiple condition

Tags: xslt

I would like to filter nodes based on multiple condition.

```
<SHOP>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>10000</kod>
      <vyrobca>APPLE</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>GOOD</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
      <obrazky/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>365</kod>
      <vyrobca>HUAWEI</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>SOMETHING</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>999</kod>
      <vyrobca>HUAWEI</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>SOMETHING</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>90000</kod>
      <vyrobca>APPLE</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>SECONDGOOD</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
      <obrazky/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>304-R-MK</kod>
      <vyrobca>APPLE</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>NOTGOOD</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
   </zasoba>
</SHOP>
```

Condition:

- keep item in output if `<vyrobca>` = APPLE and `kategorie/kategoria` = GOOD or SECONDGOOD. Remove any other where `<vyrobca>` = Apple and `kategorie/kategoria` is any other value than GOOD or SECONDGOOD. Explanation: I would like to leave all APPLE items in the output, from these two categories.
- second part of condition: leave in output everything when `<vyrobca>` = HUAWEI. `kategorie/kategoria` doesn't matter.

Example output from input above:

```
<SHOP>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>10000</kod>
      <vyrobca>APPLE</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>GOOD</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
      <obrazky/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>365</kod>
      <vyrobca>HUAWEI</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>SOMETHING</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>999</kod>
      <vyrobca>HUAWEI</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>SOMETHING</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>90000</kod>
      <vyrobca>APPLE</vyrobca>
      <kategorie>
         <kategoria>SECONDGOOD</kategoria>
      </kategorie>
      <obrazky/>
   </zasoba>
</SHOP>
```

I am trying to use this match:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="zasoba[(not(vyrobca = 'APPLE') and not(kategorie/kategoria = 'GOOD' or kategorie/kategoria = 'SECONDGOOD')) or not(vyrobca = 'HUAWEI')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But doesn't work. Operators can't be combined this way? I thought that `(not(vyrobca = 'APPLE') and not(kategorie/kategoria = 'GOOD' or kategorie/kategoria = 'SECONDGOOD'))` should work, where I made exception for APPLE and the two categories.

Comment: Why do you have `or not(vyrobca = 'HUAWEI')` in your predicate? It doesn't fit your description of what you want to achieve, and it causes the predicate to be true for all  `zasoba` nodes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  "second part of condition: leave in output everything when `<vyrobca>` = HUAWEI, for this condition `kategorie/kategoria` doesn't matter."

Comment: If I could describe my question in an if / elseif method: ```if (vyrobca == 'APPLE') and (kategorie/kategoria == 'GOOD' or kategorie/kategoria = 'SECONDGOOD') {
"this should be in output"
} elseif (vyrobca == 'HUAWEI') {
"this should be in output"
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as your 2nd template:

```
<xsl:template match="zasoba[not(vyrobca = 'APPLE' and (kategorie/kategoria = 'GOOD' or kategorie/kategoria = 'SECONDGOOD') or vyrobca = 'HUAWEI')]" />
```

---

**Explanation**:

You want to **include** `zasoba` nodes that meet the following conditions:

```
vyrobca = 'APPLE' and (kategorie/kategoria = 'GOOD' or kategorie/kategoria = 'SECONDGOOD') 
or 
vyrobca = 'HUAWEI'
```

In order to rewrite this as the predicate for the nodes to **exclude**, we just need to wrap the entire expression in `not()`.

You have:

```
(not(vyrobca = 'APPLE') and not(kategorie/kategoria = 'GOOD' or kategorie/kategoria = 'SECONDGOOD')) or not(vyrobca = 'HUAWEI')
```

To understand this better, let's drop the part about `kategorie/kategoria` and the redundant parentheses. This leaves as with:

```
not(vyrobca = 'APPLE') or not(vyrobca = 'HUAWEI')
```

which, according to [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), is the equivalent of:

```
not ( vyrobca = 'APPLE' and vyrobca = 'HUAWEI' )
```

and this is of course true for any product with a single manufacturer.

Comment: Very cool, thank you. I see it does matter where we put the brackets.

Comment: One more question. If I want to make match case insensitive I can use lower-case() function: `lower-case(kategorie/kategoria)`. It does not work with special characters? Example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBe

Comment: You should make this a new question. In short, it has nothing to do with special characters, and everything to do with having multiple `kategoria` nodes. In fact, I am surprised you're not getting an error, trying to apply `lower-case()` to a sequence of more than one item. I suspect this is a bug. Anyway, you can see the corrected version: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBe/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k, it is not a bug, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#pattern-errors: "A dynamic error or type error that occurs during the evaluation of a pattern against a particular item has the effect that the item being tested is treated as not matching the pattern. The error does not cause the transformation to fail".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In meantime I am experiencing with one more thing:, add one more condition: `and not(kategorie/kategoria = 'Removethis')`. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBe/2 It is OK to use not() in not()?

Comment: @BélaNem Why not?